# How to check if an SpringBoard alert / Safari browser popup is present?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, activator

Is there a way to check from the command-line terminal, if an alert view is shown?

I can ssh onto my iPad and wanted to check whether a basic-auth popup from either springboard or the safari browser is present. Does safari store the `state` of the alert in a specific plist/file on the device?

I can also run an app as a background service on the iPad, but will it capture the alerts shown in other apps? Can this be done via `activator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up on using a [Theos Tweak](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup) app and hooking in on `show` method of `UIAlertView`